# Jaspersoft studio multiple chart with single query

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, dataset

My database query fetches list of data like:

```
    id       key        noc       date
    1        abc        4         1-10-2016
    2        abc        12        2-10-2016
    3        abc        23        3-10-2016
    4        abc        2         4-10-2016
    5        def        23        1-10-2016
    6        def        44        2-10-2016
    7        def        12        3-10-2016
    9        def        43        4-10-2016
    10       def        43        5-10-2016
```

abc and def made those no of calls on those dates.
I want to display these data in chart.
But I am fetching this data with a single query, and I want to create 2 charts , one for abc and another for def.

How can I create multiple charts in jaspersoft with single query and making a single chart? As the number of persons making the call can be different , and I will have to create a chart for every person.

Answer (score 0):

When creating or modifying each chart you just need to link them back to the relevant dataset. This can be either the main report dataset or a sub-dataset created just to run the charts.

You only need to follow the instructions on the relevant [jaspersoft wiki page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-datasets-jaspersoft-studio) and link each new chart back to the required dataset.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your response .  Please don't just post any answer, people comes here with hope to get some clue after searching relevant documentation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For getting multiple charts from a single query you need to do :

1. First create a jasper report, and add a subreport to it. ( Make sure to make the layout growable and the width of the main group should be larger than the subgroup)
2. Create the dataset
3. Create Group on right clicking the report from outline panel.
4. Provide a group name by selecting a column.
5. Add a expression pointing the column which is grouping the data.
6. And select reset on group .
7. Don't forget to set the evaluation time  and the evaluation group

For example :

```
<chart evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="KeywordGroup">
```